# How can I replicate Google's "Glamour" effect in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, animation, effects

I need to replicate the video effect named "Glamour" in the Google Photo app using Adobe Premiere or any other video editor with professional tools. Here is a [sample](https://youtu.be/gz1ZgLVeczM). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's a simple matter of combining motion and scaling keyframes for the animation of the photos with a dip to white transition. The background can be achieved by duplicating each photo to a lower layer, scaling them up and applying a gaussian blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

1. The image is enlarged, slightly blurred and scaling up in the background
2. Another copy of the image has a white border added to it, and both fades in and scales down in front of the background. Some of these copies are at a slight angle.
3. Once the foreground image has reached its final position, a bloom filter is applied to the entire image with the amount of bloom increasing over time. It's used as a transition, so that the outgoing clip gets more and more bloom, and also fades into the incoming clip, which starts out with a lot of bloom and gets less and less over time.

So you'll need 2 layers - one for the foreground and one for the background. You'll need to blur, scale, and animate the scale of the background layer. Then you'll need to add a border to the foreground layer, animate its scale over time, and possibly rotate it. You may need to precompose that into a single layer and apply the bloom filter as a transition as described above.